# application config file clean up

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files

a c# application which I worked on in the past went through a couple of namespace changes and assembly name changes.

As a result of this my application's config file that is generated when I build is full of older stuff that is of no use to me anymore.

I've tried deleting these sections. I tried deleting the whole config file and forcing VS to build me a new one but it keeps building me a copy from a LONG time back.

How can I force my application to give me a new config file whenever I want to?

edit: question was unclear. I'll try to add more.

Let's say for example that my application was called "mytools". I then changed the assembly and namespace settings for the program and now it is called "mytoolsPLUS". When I build my application and view the mytoolsPLUS.exe.config file I see in the `<configsections>` node I have two `<sectiongroup>` nodes, usersettings and applicationsettings. Within the usersettings `<sectiongroup>` node I have an entry for `<section name=mytools.properties.settings type=sys.config.clientsettingssection....>` but I also have an entry for `<section name=mytoolsPLUS.properties.settings type=sys.config.clientsettingssection...>`

This same sort of duplication occurs under my `<connectionstrings>` node and thus is the main reason I am posting this thread today. One of my end users got confused as to which connection string they needed to adjust to point to a backup test server. I looked into it more and found that I have lots of "old fragments" left over in my config file. I like using the settings class over a full xml file for small apps like this so I would like to figure out what I have done wrong here. I hope my explanation is clear enough for those who are reading.

Thanks for reading my post!

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing/expecting when "VS builds me a new config file"?

Comment: I'd +10 this if I could. Finally just gave up and am manually creating the config file for deployment - an absolute PITA whenever we add a new setting, not to mention it being a potential source for problems.

Comment: @StingyJack I believe the OP is expecting the new file to be devoid of the old config sections (with the old, defunct, and now should-be-missing-from-the-project namespaces)

Comment: If you "Add new config file" to the project, it will be blank. I dont think this is the route he is going, so I am asking for a bit of clarification on how he arrives here.

Comment: What I am after is a config file that just has entries that match the settings listed on my "settings" tab of the application properties. When I do Clean -> Rebuild I expect that it will drop those old useless sections and build me a file with just what my app is currently configured for.

Comment: Your question and/or problem is not clear. I have never had this problem and have changed many projects namespace and never had a problem with the configuration file.

Comment: @Ramhound Did you change the namespace before or after you had a settings file? Maybe I'm just an unlucky person to have hit a similar bug in VS as the OP, but I can vouch that this problem does indeed exist.

Answer (score 0):

In your project, tree open the properties node directly under the project.

In there you will see a "Settings.settings" and "Settings.Designer.cs" file. Right click each of the files and choose "Open With.." and pick "Source code editor".

You should be able to clean up anything old from here.

You can also use a standard text editor to edit these.

Comment: when I open settings.settings with notepad I see user and application scoped settings that match with what I expect. I see nothing in here that I should delete. Changes I make to the designer file get overwritten by the newly generated one. Other than the application properties pages what else results in the generation of that settings file?

Answer (score 0):

In your project, there should be a file called App.config. You can delete the extra sectionGroups and other extraneous stuff there to clean-up your config file.